# jQuery: $.trim() spaces between words in input.val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I've seen some similar questions to mine here, but they don't really answer me...

So I'm doing this: (Inside the document ready function)

```
$("#dest").focusin(function() {
    $("#dest").val($.trim($("#dest").val()));
});
```

The ideia is when the user focus on a `input` called `#dest` trim all the space characters on it (previously added using focusout for visual comfort).

Right now, nothing is happening. :(

Hope someone can help me a bit here.

Thanks!

---

**Is this a computer related problem?**
I've tested all the code provided by commenters and none works. I'm using Firefox and Safari under OSX (Snow Leopard) 10.6.8 and also Safari under 10.8.2 (Lion) and I got the same results... OSX problem? -- **Everything is ok, check my last edit!**

---

**Final Edit and Solution thanks to Phil Klein**

My problem was using incorrectly jQuery's `trim()` function... According to the `trim()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) it does the following:

> The $.trim() function removes all newlines, spaces (including
>   non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the
>   supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of
>   the string, they are preserved.

Yesterday I didn't read the last part where it says `from the beginning and end of the supplied string` -- Sorry everyone. :(

Lucky and after the drawing above, @Phil Klein understood my mistake and helped me with a solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dest").on("focus", function() {
        var dest = $(this);
        dest.val(dest.val().split(" ").join("")); 
    });
});
```

You can [read more about the solution and see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570641/jquery-trim-and-input-val/8570679#8570679).

Thanks to @Phil Klein and also everyone who helped me on this one ;)

Comment: Maybe visual comfort can be achieved using other means (CSS padding?)

Comment: Your function is perfectly right, you only need to wrap it with $(function(){...code...}

Comment: @Thilo - CSS padding each 3 numbers?

Comment: @Nacho already at `$(document).ready` function. Thanks.

Comment: @TCB13: What's wrong with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kpXBx/)?

Comment: Can you explain what result you are seeing?  It's not real clear what your problem actually is.

Comment: @PhilKlein check the image description I added please. Thanks!

Comment: @Truth check the image description I added please. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The example below removes all spaces from the contents of the textbox on focus.  This particular example requires jQuery 1.7+ since it uses the new `.on()` API:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dest").on("focus", function() {
        var dest = $(this);
        dest.val(dest.val().split(" ").join("")); 
    });
});
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RnZ5Y/5/

Comment: You might want to include the code in your answer, jsfiddle isn't always accessible.

Comment: You example is not working, tested under Firefox and Safari. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PhilKlein after you edited the post, the spaces before and after the phrase get removed but not the one between the two words... check the image above... thanks

Comment: @TCB13 Things are finally starting to make some sense now.  You don't want to trim spaces, you want to remove them?  See my update above.

Comment: @PhilKlein you solution works well thank you ;) LOL I didn't read the last two lines of the documentation: `from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.` LOOL sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Try these : `$.trim($("#dest").val());` 
correct me if i am wrong !!

Comment: .val() should be fine for a text field.

Comment: you've one more `)` than needed at the end, but `$.trim($("#dest").val());` is still not working... thanks

Comment: @TCB13 the bracket at the end is for $.trim

Answer (score 1):

try `$("#dest").val().trim();`,it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're code above is executing before the page isn't fully ready then it's very likely that the `#dest` isn't found by jquery and the code for listening to the event doesn't get executed.

Comment: The code was in a `document ready` function, sorry by not saying that on the beginning. Anyway, I went wild and tried to place the code inside of this: `$(window).bind("load", function() {` and still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This function is working fine for your scenario. As it is taking only one space between character and not allow more than 2 space

```
$(function() {
 $("#dest").on("focusout", function() {
    var dest = $(this);
    dest.val(jQuery.trim(dest.val()));        
    dest.val(dest.val().replace(/[ ]{2,}/, ' ')); 
 });
});
```

Comment: This case has been closed a long time ago. And I admitted before the error when miss reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own function :)

look here please :)

```
function KillSpaces(phrase) {

            var totalPhrase = "";
            for (i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++)
            {
                if (phrase[i] != " ")
                {
                    totalPhrase += phrase[i];
                }
            }
            return totalPhrase;
        }
```

you can easily use it when ever you want to!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var test="for testing purposes only";
alert(killSpaces(test));
});
```